# Testing pallet_democracy proposal enactment

Tags: substrate-node, testing, pallet-democracy

I am testing a pallet using the democracy pallet, and I am struggling with the enactment step. First of all, **the proposal is correctly enacted when using the pallet in polkadot.js**: the problem occurs during testing.
The referendum infos are easily extracted through `info = Democracy::referendum_info(0);` and are :

```
Some(ReferendumInfo::Ongoing(ReferendumStatus { end: 4, proposal: Bounded::Inline(BoundedVec([11, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3], 128)), threshold: VoteThreshold::SimpleMajority, delay: 2, tally: Tally { ayes: 6, nays: 0, turnout: 6 } }))
```

So it ends at `block 4`, and is enacted with a delay of 2 blocks (`block 6` for enactment).
Fast forwarding to `block 4` correctly ends the referendum:

```
Some(ReferendumInfo::Finished { approved: true, end: 4 })
```

but going to `block 6` and beyond does not enact the proposal as it should.
Any suggestion please?